# SQL: how to use split_part in a multi table query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL and Windows.

I have a diagram of the tables and their relationships:
[image: table diagram]

**I am trying to produce a result that has firstname, lastname and country.**

firstname = because I only have "givenname" which includes first+middle names, I need to use "split_part" function to extract only the first name.

However, I cannot produce the results:

```
SELECT a.split_part(givenname, ' ', 1) AS "First Name", a.lastname AS "Last Name", b."Name" AS "Country" FROM employee as a, country as b
WHERE a.countryoforigin = b.countryID
ORDER BY givenname;
```

this shows error:
[image: error]

Now, if I don't use split_part, and directly use "givenname":

```
SELECT "givenname" AS "First Name", a.lastname AS "Last Name", b."Name" AS "Country" FROM employee as a, country as b
WHERE a.countryoforigin = b.countryID
ORDER BY givenname;
```

[image: result]

Is there a way to produce the result using split_part function? What would be the query?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using “a.split_part” for some reason, the function is just “split_part”. Table aliases are used with columns, not functions.
Therefore, the syntax should be: **split_part(a.givenname....**.

By the way, the Oracle-style join syntax you are using was superseded by ANSI join syntax about 30 years ago; you really ought to stop using it.

Here is one article about this:

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-for-beginners-joins

Comment: The "a" is referencing the Employee table since I am using multiple tables in this query. "a.split_part" can also be written as "Employee.split_part" if it helps with your answer. As per the 2nd part of your comment: I would be glad to get a better joining syntax to further educate myself. Please free free to re-write the SQL query in a way that you would have done.

Comment: You don’t seem to have understood my answer (possibly because I didn’t explain it well enough). The syntax is “split_part(a.givenname….” - you use table aliases to make it clear which table a column belongs to, you don’t apply them to functions. Also, my comment about join syntax was a recommendation that you do your own research - as that is a better way to learn rather than someone just telling you something